# Using google maps with backbone.js

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, backbone.js

I am trying to use Google maps with backbone.js. So I created a view as below. But this isn't working for me. Any inputs?

```
(function($){
    var CreateMap = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName:  "div",

        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');

            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.el, myOptions);

            this.render();
        },

        render: function() {
            return this;
        }
    });

    var mapview = new CreateMap({el: $("#map_canvas")});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: **What** to render? You need to do something in the render function to actually render a div with the corresponding map! Look at the Google map doc to see how to 'render' the map you've got in this.map` - backbone doesn't really know what/how to render, it's just an empty div in your case!

Comment: friendly note: indent your code properly.  It makes it so much easier to read.  I'm doing it to your post now so you know what I mean for future reference.

Answer (score 4):

[As PhD noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694894/using-google-maps-with-backbone-js#comment-9371174), you need to have `render` actually do something.  Here's my own working example, which assumes there is some existing `<div id="map"></div>` on the page:

```js
APP = {};

APP.Map = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
});
APP.map = new APP.Map();

APP.MapView = Backbone.View.extend({
  id: 'map',
  initialize: function(){
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.el, this.model.attributes);
    this.render();
  },
  render: function(){
    $('#map').replaceWith(this.el);
  }
});
APP.mapView = new APP.MapView({model: APP.map});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the #map_canvas div, set it up so you inject mapview.render().el into your DOM. You could do this in a backbone router class.
Calling the render function from your initialization function is not necessary.
If after this you still don't see anything, add a className to your view and make sure you have the right CSS width/height styles linked to that class.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing in `Backbone` to the scope of your wrapping function?